# Functions that make a set of functions based on given conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, generating-functions

Recently, I have been thinking about functions that make functions based on a set of conditions. Originally, I thought this is what generating functions were but after doing some research, I didn't quite find what I was thinking about.

> Specifically, I am talking about a function, $f$, (please mind the notation, I have no idea how to express this otherwise) that generates a "family" or "set" of functions given some conditions $k$.

So for example, if the conditions are that $f$ has to make a set of functions that is polynomial of degree $1$ $(ax + b)$ and has integer coefficients between $1$ and $10$ and the intercept is also made up of integer coefficients between $1$ and $10$ then that set of functions has $100$ polynomials in it.

In programming, I can make a pure function which does this. Below is the mathematica code.

```
(Range[1, 5] + #[x]) & /@ {a, b, c, d, e}
Flatten[%]
```

So, the above will generate

`{1 + a[x], 2 + a[x], 3 + a[x], 4 + a[x], 5 + a[x], 1 + b[x], 2 + b[x],
 3 + b[x], 4 + b[x], 5 + b[x], 1 + c[x], 2 + c[x], 3 + c[x], 
 4 + c[x], 5 + c[x], 1 + d[x], 2 + d[x], 3 + d[x], 4 + d[x], 5 + d[x],
 1 + e[x], 2 + e[x], 3 + e[x], 4 + e[x], 5 + e[x]}`

In this case, the conditions are that $y$-intercepts have to be between $1$ and $5$ and the $x$ can be any value `{a, b, c, d, e}`.

> I was wondering what branch of mathematics this is related to and where can I find the necessary resources to learn more about this? Furthermore, does what I have above make sense?

Thanks a lot for your time!

P.S. Can someone tag this correctly?

Comment: Dear Jeel Shah, would you mind to speak more of why are you interested in such function generators? In which problems of yours do they show up? For what you say they just seem like functions of several variables, some of them natural and others real.

Comment: Hi moonshine, I was doing some functional programming and was just messing around with some pure functions (lambda functions) to do random things. I thought about the above and thought it was cool that you can make functions that can make other functions and study the result. I wanted to see which field of mathematics this related to so I can study this further. They serve no purpose (for now) other than intriguing the curiosity.